# Incorrect java version for the build?

Tags: android

I have installed java, two times, /usr/lib/jvm contains three folders (default java, java-1.6-openjdk ,java-6-openjdk)
when I try

make -j4

it gives me the output:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
************************************************************
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: java version "1.6.0_20".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    http://source.android.com/source/download.html
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:131: *** stop.  Stop.
```

the main version is the same, only the minor one is different, i cant find java 1.6_0, what is my solution now?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

download appropriate sun jdk from :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u31-oth-JPR

and then try building

Comment: I've had luck with jdk1.6.0_27